How to use mapbox SupportMapFragment to dynamically add map on an another activity Android
How can I use this sample code: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/legacy/maps/examples/support-map-fragment/ for my app? this sample code extends AppCompatActivity instead of it being a Fragment so I can't add it on my navigation activity that has the layout for my bottom navigation bar and the FragmentManager.
Overall, what I want to achieve is a bottom navigation bar that could dynamically add and replace the map fragment with other fragments any examples would be appreciated. I've read the mapbox docs fragment examples but I don't know how to apply them for my use case.
Using the said example, can I just return a SupportMapFragment instance on my class using a getter function so that it could be used by the FragmentManager of my navigation activity?

Solved this by extending Fragment instead of AppCompatActivity and just replacing Activity lifecycle methods like onCreated to onViewCreated and using requireActivity() for any arguments requiring the activity context.
